# Top Answers section on network profile shows answers with less than five votes

Tags: bug, status-completed, network-profile, top-answers

Stack Exchange network profiles show the top questions & answers with 5 vote or more votes, but the following profile shows answers which only have 3 & 4 votes. How it this possible, is it a bug?

[image: screenshot of top answers section with answers with score < 5]

Comment: @Ravindra On an unrelated note, you seem to have separate sets of accounts: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1684977/ravindra-bagale) | [two](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1759517/ravindra-bagale) --would you like them to be merged?

Comment: @Emmett: yes i want to merge old account into new one.

Comment: Ok, your accounts have been merged.

Comment: @Emmett: i think tags on profile pages not merged i.e. total number of answers in perticular tag

Comment: On Stack Overflow? Which tag?

Comment: yes,on stackoverflow

Comment: i have answered c# questions with total of more than 32 votes, but it showing only 11 score

Comment: Tag stats are updated/cached daily -- this will be corrected within 24 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had some bad data cached for the user in question, and to add further confusion, our "no top questions/answers" message is misleading. We are changing it to:

> No answers with score of 5 or more

I've fixed up the [network profile for the user in question](https://stackexchange.com/users/1860280/ravindra-bagale).