# Use "score" instead of "votes" in the list of questions

Tags: feature-request, status-review, wording, question-lists, score

When viewing questions in the normal, "Interesting Questions" tab, (or any other view for that matter), the question's score is displayed to its left, and is labeled "votes".

[image: Votes]

But is it the correct word to use? Wouldn't "Score" be more appropriate (because a score of "1" doesn't necessarily mean "1 votes", it could mean "100 upvotes and 99 downvotes").

My suggestion, use "score"

[image: Score]

Your thoughts?

Comment: How about `vote score`?

Comment: @Oded: Possible, but isn't it a bit too long and would break the layout? http://pokit.org/get/img/352389e53dccc8d9e040a371793ce68b.png

Comment: Possibly. But there is lots of context lost if one uses `score` alone. Not sure that would be the best word, but I can't think of an alternative that has voting semantics attached (perhaps someone on [English](http://english.stackexchange.com/) can help...)

Comment: "Tally", maybe? *(Disclaimer: I'm not on [English](http://english.stackexchange.com/). Yet.)*

Comment: @UphillLuge: But it isn't the **number** of votes the question has, it's the **sum** of it. That's why I don't think "Votes" is the appropriate word.

Comment: Let's note for posterity that [this arguably related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153513/top-answers-section-on-network-profile-shows-answers-with-less-than-five-votes) was posted here a few minutes before this one. Maybe we actually have to be more precise and consistent with the terminology we use, at least in more competition-sensitive areas of the site.

Comment: I agree with the concept but disagree with the terminology `score`. Score, in general sense, means how much point or runs or goals i have did.... e.g. In cricket, if i say i scored 200 runs, it means i made 200 runs without taking into account of others. No plus or minus. The term should be change from votes but `score` isn't appropriate in my opinion.

Comment: @itachi: Well, the [meta-tag:score] meta tags states that score "means the total number of upvotes minus the total number of downvotes". So I'd argue it's pretty darn accurate.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I just noticed that.... I guess there sould be a question on this regard too as well(if not already exists).

Comment: What's *"the score"* @V2Blast? I mean *"votes"* sounds cool, at least it gives the impression of democracy... It could also be called *"bottom line"*, "*balance*" or *"imbalance"* - in *"the force"* that is; why not call *"deviation"* or *"difference"*. Next folks will complained they clicked *"the score"* expecting and [OST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundtrack)...

Comment: @Oded perhaps `Net Votes` would work better? it's shorter than vote score (2 only characters longer than answers for sizing concerns), more accurate than just votes and avoids the gamification issue that people have with the word score.

Comment: I looked at synonyms of score and the only one that kind of was okay, was `rating` but it isn't a unit either.

Answer (score 32):

Looking at what done for this question, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions reports 4 votes, but the question actually got 6 votes: 5 up-votes, and 1 down-vote.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

4 is really the score of the question: the difference between the number of up-votes, and the number of down-votes. *Votes* for me means the number of votes, not the score a post has.

*Score* should be an understood word, on Stack Exchange, as it is already used in the description of some badges, such as [Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/901/convention) ("10 posts with a score of 2 on meta"), or [Disciplined](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/37/disciplined) ("Deleted own post with score of 3 or higher"). I would not say it is a word that Stack Exchange users don't see in other places on Stack Exchange.

Comment: That's indeed true for most SE users, but from an outsider or a beginner's point of view, wouldn't using `score` emphasize the gamification aspects of the system in a (possibly) undesirable way? I'm not convinced it's the right term to use here. (There's a reason why we use `reputation` instead of `experience` after all ;)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: That's true, but even the [meta-tag:score] tag's wiki refers to it as the correct word.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I see your point, even if the only words I can think of are synonyms of _score_, such as _rate_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, same here (I think `tally` might be correct but is definitely not sexy enough). When I dig further I'm tempted to fall back to terms like `decision` or `value`, that do not have much in common with the sum of votes on a post, or at least not in our context.

Answer (score 13):

This has been a long time coming, **and we're not quite done yet**! However I'd like to update you folks that we've just pushed some changes to wording all around the website regarding "votes".

Our main goal was to switch to "Score" where it made sense, which on this first pass meant:

- The layout doesn't display the word "Score" as a unit. (e.g.: "15 score" as opposed to "15 votes" just seem weird to us right now)
- The number displayed is an actual "Score", which as described by you folks, is the combination of upvotes and downvotes

Unfortunately these restrictions mean that **question listings all around the website will remain unchanged for now**. We are working to find better wording for "Score" that can also be used as a unit (e.g.: "points"), and on a plan to implement those with minimum negative impact to you.

As usual, thanks for reporting this issue, we appreciate the help! Ironing out inconsistencies that make the website more confusing and less welcoming is one of our priorities for this year.

Comment: Why not just write score as a label instead of as units? I never read "votes" as units. I thought it was a label, i.e. Votes: 10+/2- Score: 8. (Well, at least not until the views got rearranged.)

Comment: @ColleenV exactly because of what you said: our old layout allowed us to get by with "Score" being a label. The new layout (and some other places around the website) put the data and the label together, which require a unit-like word to not read weirdly.

Comment: Maybe the problem is the new layout and not the word "score". I don't mean to jump on the dog pile, because I understand how complex an undertaking it is to unwind a code base that evolved over more than a decade and ended up far surpassing what the original vision was for its functionality. I just worry that "finding a better wording" is treating a symptom and not a cause. Replacing vocabulary that is widely used and understood throughout the user base should only be done with extreme caution. I'd rather see the label gone than replaced with "user appreciation rating units" or whatever.

Comment: @ColleenV that's a fair observation, and definitely one we have in mind. It is important to us to provide both a consistent experience and take advantage of existing widely used vocabulary, which is why we're stepping cautiously here.

Comment: I like [Andrew's suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153515/use-score-instead-of-votes-in-the-list-of-questions#comment1244622_153515) of "Net Votes".

Comment: Frankly, I do not see why "score: N" reads any more awkward than "N votes". This also avoids the embarrassing "1 vote**s**" pluralization bug neatly while aligning the wording with what community is used to - "score".

Comment: @OlegValter Problem is that then the numbers wouldn't all be on the left. The current state looks more like work in progress. There is still the search for a better alternative ongoing.  Visitors might be somewhat confused when reading this feature request seeing no visible change in the question list and status completed as tag.

Comment: Right! The number itself should still be in evidence in contrast with the label. 

I'll bring "net votes" to folks in here as well!

I agree that this status-complete might confuse some folks, but I was instructed by our triage team to do so, since the layout from the request doesn't even match our upcoming stuff. It is in our roadmap to fix this though!

(Also, I've fixed the pluralization issues in a couple of places! Hopefully I got the one that was bothering you once folks translate it :D)

Comment: @Trilarion well, another thing I do not get these days is the "one layout to rule them all" :) but in this case, I'd just go ahead and change *all* stats to follow the "Label: N" approach - no pluralization bugs, presentational unity, no concern for "better unit wording". P.S. I did not notice the post was marked [status-completed], btw (was pointed to the answer from a chat room) - it does look like WIP to me. Just wanted to add 2 cents that "just seem weird" sounds like weak justification for not going all-in with the change, IMO

Comment: That said, "net votes" does not seem too bad and can be a reasonable concession as this is what score essentially is. Although I would still advise the team to go with "score" as the latter is well-known and has a lot of references, while the former is not used (and thus has a high potential for generaring confusion amongst users, as well as requires a lot of busywork for updating references)

Comment: Not to be a wet blanket, but "Net Votes" isn't correct either. +8/-2 would be 10 net votes, not 6. @CaveJohnson The solution if we must have units is to display both up and down votes.

Comment: @ColleenV oh yea that's right.

Comment: @ColleenV 10 would be the total votes, 6 would indeed be net votes (i.e where downvotes count negative) but votes itself doesn't say which of it it is. Net or total.

Comment: @Trilarion I disagree. Net is "after all deductions have been made" or "Ultimate/Final" not "the sum". We say "net profit", not "net dollars". Also, net doesn't fit because score changes. We don't finalize score. Generally, "net" is used in contrast with "gross"... it just doesn't make sense in this context (as an adjective).

Comment: @ColleenV Deduct down votes from up votes (makes sense to me) and you get net votes. My vote in this case is for either score, rating or net vote. Score sounds great to me. We have to write something there. The question is what most people can live best with.

Comment: @Trilarion The point of the labels is to communicate something to a typical user, not twist a dictionary definition until it fits the purpose. If it's this hard to figure out what word to use for a label, then the UI isn't communicating meaning very well. It would be far more informative to just show the up votes and down votes, and it would help people understand whether the score was controversial or not. I still don't understand why everyone can't see the positive and negative vote totals, which is much more meaningful than score.

Comment: @ColleenV "The point of the labels is to communicate something to a typical user.." Exactly. Anything goes as long as enough people understand what is meant. For 10 years it was votes which was wrong as pointed out here but only less than 100 people complained. Obviously it can remain votes then. I agree with you that showing up and down votes separately would be nice too but this would be a different feature request. Better discuss it at its own question

Comment: It looks like you're going with "Score of *N*"? That's how it appears to me on a completed suggested edit review on Mathematics right now.

Comment: thanks for the lively discussion here folks! People are monitoring ideas and debating within.
@TheAmplitwist that is correct for a few places where we believed it made sense.

Comment: "-10 votes" is like "-10 cats". It makes zero sense. It's wrong, it's incorrect in English, and it's plain wrong. I really, honestly, can't understand what is so hard to replace it with, for example "Score of -10" which is: 1) Correct. 2) Makes total  sense. 3) Easy to implement, it's just changing some words. SE works in anti-KIS principle, you always make everything complicated and confusing, and it's really a shame.

Answer (score 4):

Not only would this be a more accurate term, it would also avoid the famous [pluralization bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/259693)! "1 Score" is just as proper as "2 Score", but "1 Votes" just looks terrible.

Answer (score -4):

It's been pointed out that "score" is a bit confusing for new users, especially given that it already has a perfectly ordinary meaning that's not obviously out of scope. But the OP is correct that "votes" is not merely a bit confusing, but wrong and misleading in important ways. And "vote score" or similar, while neither misleading nor confusing, is too long to fit.

Instead of any of those, then, I suggest using "voting". This has the advantage of clearly tying back to concept of votes up or down, but without implying that it actually counts the total *number* of votes. Its meaning is deliberately skewed from the normal in an obvious way, so users unfamiliar with it, rather than being misled, will know that the site is using it in an idiosyncratic way, and will know to find out what the actual meaning is. A tooltip can then inform them efficiently that it's the *sum* of up and down votes.

In other words, treat it as a short caption for a figure ("for question quality, see fig 1-21, *voting*"), rather than an inline phrase ("24 votes", "Score 2").