# Should the front page say "score" rather than "votes"?

Tags: discussion, wording, score, homepage

This is just a minor detail, but the number we see on the front page is not really the number of *votes*. It's the *score* of the question.

[image]

For example, the number 161 here is the *score*, not the *votes*. There are  currently 195 *votes* on that [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285467/321647), 17 of them downvotes. Not that it's a big deal or anything. Most users know how it works. But maybe some new users don't know, though? Changing it to *score* would perhaps be more correct and clear? I'm only mentioning it since it would seem like a rather simple change to make.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Use “score” instead of “votes” in the list of questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153515/300411)