# Inconsistent tooltips for the post's score on flag history page between questions and answers

Tags: bug, tooltips, flag-history, score

On the flag history page, each post shown has its score as a number on the left-hand side. Hovering over this brings up a tooltip. However, whether the number itself is included in said hovertext depends on whether the post in question is a question or answer. Some examples follow, in the order of accepted/positive/negative:

#### Answers

- [image: tooltip for an accepted answer]

  > total number of votes for this answer, which was accepted as the correct answer by the question owner
- [image: tooltip for a positively scored answer]

  > total number of votes for this answer
- [image: tooltip for a negatively scored answer]

  > total number of votes for this answer

#### Questions

- [image: tooltip for a question with an accepted answer]

  > 4 votes, with an accepted answer
- [image: tooltip for a positively scored question]

  > 3 votes

  <sub>not the real number of votes (this Q is +10/-7) but that's a battle for [another time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153515/1017231)</sub>
- [image: tooltip for a negatively scored question]

  > -3 votes

Please standardize this one way or the other.