# upvoteCount contains post score, and downvoteCount is unused

Tags: bug, score

According to https://schema.org/Comment:

> | Property | Expected Type | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | [`downvoteCount`](https://schema.org/downvoteCount) | [Integer](https://schema.org/Integer) | The number of downvotes this question, answer or comment has received from the community. |
> | [`upvoteCount`](https://schema.org/upvoteCount) | [Integer](https://schema.org/Integer) | The number of upvotes this question, answer or comment has received from the community. |

However, Stack Exchange's HTML looks like:

> ```html
>         <div class="js-vote-count flex--item d-flex fd-column ai-center fc-theme-body-font fw-bold fs-subheading py4"
>              itemprop="upvoteCount"
>              data-value="-363">
>             -363
>         </div>
> ```

Related: [Use "score" instead of "votes" in the list of questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153515/308065)

Comment: I wasn't really sure where to post this – because this schema was _designed_ for Stack Exchange. So maybe the documentation is at fault? I'd be inclined to err on the side of "people are unlikely to be inspecting [tag soup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_soup) when they have perfectly good documentation" and say there's probably software out there assuming that `upvoteCount - downvoteCount` is a meaningful operation.