# I thought top posts count 5 score

Tags: bug, network-profile, top-answers

When I was a starter for the Network, I read that all the posts, that have a score of 5 or more, are shown as the Top posts on the Network profile of the user.

```
// Just for fun! 
bool showPost = false;
foreach (var row in posts) {
   int upVotes = post.getUpVotes(postId);
   if(upVotes >= 5) {
      showPost = true;
   }
}
```

Today, when I went to the page, I just saw my answer that was upvoted just 4 times. It was being shown there in the list too.

**[jquery validation - with form tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834158/jquery-validation-with-form-tag/21834245#21834245)** This is the post.

Here is the image for the page:

[image]

Can I know why is the post with **4** score present at the list?

Comment: Related: [Top Answers section on network profile shows answers with less than five votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153513)

Comment: @MartijnPieters, oh so it was a small bug in the site, once again! :D http://goo.gl/g8Amfh this would be my present for Stack Exchange in case of bugs ;) hehehe .. Just for fun!

Comment: Good chance it's case of unupvote i.e. it *had* 5 upvotes for a while, then one of them undid the vote. It was edited, so if someone upvoted before the edit he could retract the vote at any later point.

Comment: Hmm... another possible reason is that it actually has [five votes](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/174849/all-votes-for-answer-21834245), one of them being the answer being accepted. Just a wild guess but who knows.