# Answers with >=5 score not appearing, while others with score == 4 do in network profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, network-profile

I recently noticed that [my network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/2251762/fedorqui) has enough answers with score >= 5 to full the 10 pages of it.

However, I see at least [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31812356/1983854) that has a score of 5 and does not appear, whereas two with a score of 4 do:

[image]

I  see this has happened before: [Top Answers section on network profile shows answers with less than five votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153513/209901).

Comment: This is due to slight data drift between the "real" data (on each site), and the *centrally aggregated* data that that particular API accesses; the UI then looks up the *actual* scores from the real data. Obviously we don't *intend* for there to be a delta, but there isn't a *trivial* way to avoid this; looking to see what I can do...

Comment: @MarcGravell it looks kind of fixed : )

Comment: we needed a [status-kind-of-fixed] tag

Comment: @MarcGravell I kind-of-agree : D Thanks for fixing this!

Comment: @Adam Lear funny enough, I now have the exact same situation with 5 instead of 4 and 6 instead of 5. That is, answers with a score of 6 not appearing ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38853751/1983854), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36687154/1983854)) while two with a score of 5 do show.

Comment: @MarcGravell Can you work whatever magic you did here again? (See comment above.)